# unzip unable to find file with spaces in file name

Tags: command-line, files

I'm a psychology student at the VU Amsterdam. For my statistic courses this software called `IBM SPSS statistics` is required andabsolutly neccesary. I bought it of the official website and downloaded the .zip file. I've tried to open it with `archivemanager` and it was extracting something but in the end it always said:

```
Invalid url: '/home/mumen420/.cache/.fr-Q2kVc7/IBM' given, exiting
```

I've tried to use the `unzip` command and that always responds with

```
mumen420@Laptop-chan:~$ unzip IBM SPSS Statistics 24 Linux.zip
unzip:  cannot find or open IBM, IBM.zip or IBM.ZIP
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use `\` for the escape character so that it knows there is a space where ever there is a space in the filename:

```
unzip IBM\ SPSS\ Statistics\ 24\ Linux.zip
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Besides from escaping, you can also quote the file name:

```
unzip "IBM SPSS Statistics 24 Linux.zip"
```

or

```
unzip 'IBM SPSS Statistics 24 Linux.zip'
```

Comment: What is the difference between the two types of quoting?

Comment: @pa4080 variable expansion, command substitution, history expansion etc. take place in double quotes, but not in single quotes.

Comment: @pa4080 There is no difference at all in this exact case. ;P

Comment: For sure in this exact case :)